# How to get R data frames to keep and display unicode characters

Tags: r, unicode, centos, centos6

How can I include Greek letters in my data frames (and save them into Excel worksheets that way)? When I try, they are replaced with spaces (with `data_frame` from `dplyr`) or `X` (in `data.frame`).

```
d <- data_frame(` L` = 5, ` ` = 6)

names(d)
#[1] " L" " " 

d <- data.frame(` L` = 5, ` ` = 6)

names(d)
#[1] "X.L" "X." 

Sys.setlocale(locale="UTF-8")
#[1] ""
#Warning message:
#In Sys.setlocale(locale = "UTF-8") :
#  OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored

cat *-release
# CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Sys.getlocale()
#[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;
#     LC_NUMERIC=C;
#     LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;
#     LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;
#     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;
#     LC_MESSAGES=en_US.iso885915;
#     LC_PAPER=en_US.iso885915;
#     LC_NAME=en_US.iso885915;
#     LC_ADDRESS=en_US.iso885915;
#     LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.iso885915;
#     LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.iso885915;
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.iso885915"
```

Interestingly, I can't even get them to show up from the browser. The first space should be a `greek small letter mu` and the second should be a `greek small letter beta`.

Comment: interestingly, I can't even get them to show up from the browser. The first space should be a `greek small letter mu` and the second should be a `greek small letter beta`.

Comment: As far as I know, R doesn't support unicode variable names. It causes an error for me with and without surrounding backticks. You could keep a UTF-8 encoded character vector containing the desired variable names, then write that to your Excel file prior to writing the rest of your data.